# How do I increment a PFUser score that is not currentUser with MasterKey?

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am working on a simple iOS game using parse.com as my backend.

I would like to increment the scores of all PFUsers playing a game when the game ends, NOT just currentUser.

I call my cloud code using objective c as follows.  (objects is an array which contains all the users in the game)

```
for (PFObject *object in objects){
    int count = 100; 

    NSNumber *addToScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:count];

    [PFCloud callFunction:@"incrementUserScore" withParameters:@{
                @"userId":object.objectId, @"baseNumber":addToScore }];

}
```

The cloud code itself is given below

```
Parse.Cloud.define('incrementUserScore', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId,
    addToScore = request.params.baseNumber,

    User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
    user = new User({ objectId: userId }); 

    user.increment("score",addToScore);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
       response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
       response.error(error)
    });
});
```

My game crashes when the cloud code is called.

I am a beginner programer and have not used javascript much at all.
Does anybody see anything obviously wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So your cloud code is the issue. You need to create a query for each user object, and from that query set the score and save.

There is all of this information at:

```
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions
```

You'll want to fetch the user object based on the userId you're passing in and then change that object's score to the appropriate value. Below is a sample cloud function from the documentation that should give you a start for the query part of this task.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("averageStars", function(request, response) {
 var query = new Parse.Query("Review");
 query.equalTo("movie", request.params.movie);
 query.find({
   success: function(results) {
   var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
     sum += results[i].get("stars");
   }
   response.success(sum / results.length);
 },
 error: function() {
   response.error("movie lookup failed");
 }
 });
});
```

Comment: The reason there is no query in the cloud code is because I previously queried the PFUsers in order to populate the objects array.  Is it still necessary to add a query in the cloud code?

Comment: Yes so that you can get the user object you want to modify.

Comment: What if I pass the user objects into the cloud code function as arguments?

Comment: That would be unwise I believe. It's better to just pass user IDs and fetch them. Passing user objects could lead to invalid objects in the two different environments